# What is the life expectancy of different Races?

Tags: races, the-dark-eye

How well defined are the boundaries and how many years does a

- Human
- Elf
- Half-Elf
- Halfling
- Dwarf
- Gnome
- Ogre
- Orc
- Half-Orc
- Golem
- Giants

normally, in average, have in DSA5?

Comment: Which game system and edition are you asking about?

Comment: Just in general - maybe in average?
I just want a baseline to start off with, some number that most of the systems agree on.

Comment: It can vary wildly between game systems and even different editions of the same system. We're not going to average together the **thousands** of different game systems that have been published for you. You need to pick *one* game and edition for this to be answerable.

Comment: Basically I would be needing an estimate for a MMO-RPG RP world (Black Desert Online) but as the lore is very sparse on that one, I would be just ok with numbers from PnP systems like D&D or DSA(the dark eye).

Comment: You probably also need to narrow this down to a set list of races you care about. Saying "etc." implies you want to know about every race. Again, some systems have over a thousand races.

Comment: Again, you need to pick **one** system (like D&D or DSA) *and* one edition of that system (such as D&D 3.5) and then ask about a concrete (*not* open-ended) list of races from that system. The numbers for Black Desert Online might be completely different from the ones in D&D, which might be completely different from the ones in DSA. Also, questions about MMOs are entirely off-topic here, you would need to ask in [gaming.se].

Comment: First off, thanks for the heads-up, I edited the list and I would like to concentrate on DSA as the system.

Comment: OK, this looks answerable now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### In chapter 4 of the core rulebook of the dark eye 5 are some information:

(Page numbers are for the german version)

- **Human:** about 80 years (sometimes 90-100 or above) (p.90)
- **Elf:** until they fulfilled their purpose in life (then they pass away within days) (p. 91)
- **Half-Elf:** about 100 years (their appearance stays young until shortly before they die)
- **Dwarf:** about 300-400 years (it is not unusual that they get even older)
- **Orc:** about 40 years (p. 27, "Aventurischer Almanach")

#### Information from older editions:

(While the ruleset changed, the world is the same, so I would assume that the life expectancy of the older books stays correct)

- **Ogre:** 130 years
- **Half-Orc:** 50-60 years
- **Giants:** immortal

#### Other information (regarding Aventuria):

- Halflings do not exist per se, but you could compare them to the "Hügelzwerge" (Hilldwarves), which left the mines, and are described as good-tempered and buoyant. Thus, see dwarves for their life expectancy.
- Gnomes aren't a race either. It is a disdainful way to call a "Geode", which is a dwarven druid/mage with focus on elemental magic.
- Golems are constructs and created through magic, so there is no real life expectancy.

Comment: You forgot: Grolme (Kender-like, 30), Risso (Fishmen, 130), Achaz (reptile people, 130 (250 on one island)), Goblin (35), Trollzacker&Rochschaz (a barbarian tribe with supposed troll blood & their super tall members, 50-60), Nivese (sami people that have members that turns into wolfs, 90) ; ; source: wiki-aventurica.de

Comment: @Trish I answered those in the question. But yes at least some of those races are very important for the setting.

Comment: Trollzacker/Rochshaz and Nivesen are humans